# Open specific tab from Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-tablayout

I am trying to set the focus on the specific tab after click on Push Notification
I am unable to redirect it, here is my code

```
 Intent intent_chat=new Intent(this, HomeChatFragment.class);
 pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent_chat,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Any kind of guidance will be great, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by specific tab?

Comment: @indramurari I have four tabs in my home screen but when I click on push it should be redirected to Chat Tab(which is 3rd tab)

Comment: Send some flag from intent and handle it in your activity that if you are getting specific flag then open specific tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent_chat=new Intent(this, HomeChatFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("someFlag", 2); //tab position to open
pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent_chat,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in your `HomeChatFragment.java` do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
        int i;
        if(getIntent() != null) {
            i = getIntent().getIntExtra("someFlag", -1);
       }
       if(i != -1) {
           yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send some flag from intent & by using bundle get that flag in activity & set to tablayout Like:

```
    selectionTab = bundle.getInt("selectionTab");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(selectionTab).select();                
tabLayout.getTabAt(selectionTab).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solve your problem . Just try it

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(UtilityConstants.key, value);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, _id,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

if you have any query then comment here!!